# In C#, what does using a dollar sign do in Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#-6.0, console.writeline

thank you for looking at my question, to verify what i mean

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {variable}");
```

I am curious to the effect that the $ has on the output from Console.WriteLine

Comment: I will in the future, I'm new to programming in general so I was completely unaware of this.

Answer (score 14):

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {variable}");
```

Is I think equal to:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello {0}", variable));
```

It just moves the parameter into the index position as if you were formatting it.

Answer (score 6):

It is a new feature to use in addition to `string.Format`

It's called [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)

Comment: $"<text> {<interpolated-expression> [,<field-width>] [<:format-string>] } <text> ..."